# impresspages parse the renturn data from getMenuItems class

Tags: arrays, impresspages

I want to build a custom menu output so I am calling this class:

```
$pages = \Ip\Menu\Helper::getMenuItems('menu1');
```

It returns this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Ip\Menu\Item Object
    (
        [title:protected] => Home
        [pageTitle:protected] => 
        [url:protected] => http://porto.gigaweb.me/home
        [target:protected] => 
        [selected:protected] => 
        [current:protected] => 1
        [children:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => Ip\Menu\Item Object
                    (
                        [title:protected] => Lorem ipsum
                        [pageTitle:protected] => 
                        [url:protected] => http://porto.gigaweb.me/lorem-ipsumy
                        [target:protected] => 
                        [selected:protected] => 
                        [current:protected] => 
                        [children:protected] => 
                        [depth:protected] => 2
                        [disabled:protected] => 0
                        [blank:protected] => 0
                    )

                [1] => Ip\Menu\Item Object
                    (
                        [title:protected] => about
                        [pageTitle:protected] => 
                        [url:protected] => http://porto.gigaweb.me/about
                        [target:protected] => 
                        [selected:protected] => 
                        [current:protected] => 
                        [children:protected] => 
                        [depth:protected] => 2
                        [disabled:protected] => 0
                        [blank:protected] => 0
                    )
            )
        [depth:protected] => 1
        [disabled:protected] => 0
        [blank:protected] => 0
    )
)
```

I have tried to turn it into an array but it returns value like this [*title].
I want to loop through it and output the values but cant seem to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is an array of objects. Not an array of arrays. So you have to do something like this:

```
foreach ($pages as $menuItem) {
  $page->getTitle();
}
```

You can find other methods of $page object here http://www.impresspages.org/menu-item

Please keep in mind, that you are getting MenuItem objects, not Page objects.